# Bright green + white = not really readable

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, meta

This is a very minor issue, but I figured I'd put it out there: [When a tag is edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/31687/list) on a question on meta, it is displayed in the log as bright green with white text. On my screen I can't read it unless I select the text.

[image]

Due to a request, [here is the problem pinpointed with great accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7FhV.png).

Comment: here you go (character limit)

Comment: I still can't see what the problem is. Could you please be more specific? :-)

Comment: @konamiman: No. No I can't.

Comment: You know that the intent of an image is to convey more info than pure text. If you delete this information from the screen shot, than it is totally worthless.

Comment: @john: sorry I didn't get your point. The first screen was to show the problem. the second one was to make farseeker happy

Comment: did you guys clicked on the link "When a tag is edited"? it's pretty clear there what marcgg means... even if there is no hand-drawn circle there :P

Comment: *the second one was to make **Katerina and waves** happy* FTFY

Comment: @marcgg: First the screen shot must be informative, second it must have freehand circles! You should have shot something like the page I've linked to.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/name-of-newly-added-tag-in-edit-history-is-hard-to-read-when-hovered That one is status-declined for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok,

```
.diff-add
{
    background: #97FF97;
    color: #003800;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

<del>I'm not aware of the support on IE8, but most other browsers have some support for a translucent or transparent background.</del>

---

Scratch that, just add to the style page:

```
.moderator-tag .diff-add {color:black;}
```